# Ionic - Create multiple charts with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic 3 , Angular 4 :- Have to display no of charts dynamically. Show the house’s utilities consumptions in bar chart. if Logged user has more than houses , then show number of house  consumption graphs.

Now I have problems, how to dynamically show the graphs.

This is my code.

ts file

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-consumption',
    templateUrl: 'Consumption.html',
    providers: [ConsumptionController]
})
export class ConsumptionPage {
  isServiceLoaded : boolean =  false;
  barChart: any;
  secondbarChart: any;

   msslList : any[];
   msslNum: number;

   barChartLabels : any[];
   barChartLabel: string[];
   barChartType: string = 'bar';
   barChartLegend: boolean = true;
   barChartData: any[];
   consumptionList: Array<Consumption>
   barChartOptions = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
   };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private _progressLoader: ProgressLoader,
              private _consController: ConsumptionController,
              private connectivityService: ConnectivityService) {

  }


    getConsumptionData() {
     this._consController.consumptionService("1").then((result) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < msslConsumptionList.length; i++) {
            const consObj                     = msslConsumptionList[i];
               usagesList[usagesList.length]     = consObj.usage;
               usageMonthList[usagesList.length] = consObj.startDate;  

            }

        this.barChartLabels = usageMonthList;
          this.barChartData   = [{ data: usagesList, label: 'Series A' } ];

    });
    this.isServiceLoaded = true;

   }
}
```

This is my HTML :

```
<ion-content *ngIf="isServiceLoaded">
    <br>
    <ion-card>
        {{ msslList }} {{ msslNum }} -->

        <div *ngFor="let mssl of msslList; let i=index">
            Testing

            <ion-card-header class="center">
                150 Tanjong Pagar Road, S088456
            </ion-card-header>

            <ion-card-content>
                <canvas baseChart [datasets]=" barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
            </canvas>

            </ion-card-content>


        </div>
    </ion-card>
```

Here My question is :

1. How to show no of graphs dynamically?
2. My obstacle is-  dynamically declare variables and assign that variable to to html canvas id

eg.   `barChartLabels1` , `barChartLabels2` etc 
      `barChartData`, `barChartData2`  etc

I tried like below stated code, but in `ts` how to declare local variable dynamically ?

```
<canvas baseChart [datasets]=" barChartData[i]" [labels]="barChartLabels[i]“ [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
            </canvas>
```

Please guide me. This is the 2nd whole day i spent for this but unfortunately i couldn't achieve my target.

Can't it be done ? Any limitation in ionic ?